# jQuery each does not execute html for each element in object

Tags: jquery, object, each

Here's the code:

```
var object = [
  {'item1': 'value1a', 'item2':'value2a', 'item3':'value3a'},
  {'item1': 'value1b', 'item2':'value2b', 'item3':'value3b'},
];


$.each(object, function(key,value) { 
  $('.my-div').html('<li>'+ value.item1 + '</li>');
});
```

This outputs only one `<li>value1b</li>`. For some reason skips over all except the last iteration.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's overwriting all your HTML instead of appending it.

Change

```
$('.my-div').html('<li>'+ value.item1 + '</li>');
```

to

```
$('.my-div').append('<li>'+ value.item1 + '</li>');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/hpLa6/1/

Comment: @djreed Each iteration of your loop replaces the entire contents of `.my-div` with a single `li`. This can be solved by appending `append` instead of replace all contents `html`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting it on each iteration. You need to do like

`$('.my-div').html($('.my-div').html()+'<li>'+ value.item1 + '</li>');`

edited to fix bug

Comment: you obviously don't understand the purpose of downvoting

Comment: Sorry bro your code won't work using `$(this)` like that http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/hpLa6/2/

Comment: @AlienWebguy: p.s. - if you wanna downvote for "less efficient" answers...how about I downvote you for selecting the node every iteration of the .each(), since it would be more efficient to += a var and then then pass the full var to the selected node

Comment: Your code is broken. Don't get pissy at me for downvoting your broken code. All you had to do was error-check it ahead of time. If you fix your bug, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I'll accept the downvote for the bug, but that's not why you downvoted me. You went back and edited.

Comment: Oh boy. Just fix your bug and I'll remove the downvote lol. Seriously we're both nerds we should be on the same side ;)

Comment: I fixed it. And I don't disagree with the lack of efficiency. It was mostly for just illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The previous edits are being overwritten.  Its the equivalent of doing this:

```
int total = 0;
for (int x=0;x<10;++x)
   total = x;
```

(obviously a different programming language)

The above answer would be "9" instead of the expected answer.

You need to append each html call.

Edit:

Holy crap people beat me... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use jQuery for this, why not just use a simple:

```
for (var obj in objects) {
    $('.my-div').append('<li>'+ obj.item1 + '</li>');
}
```

Tip: I would avoid using the id `object` in any language

Answer (score 0):

Since *some* people like to downvote because of inefficiency... this would be more efficient, as it selects the node only once

```
$(function(){
      var object = [
          {'item1': 'value1a', 'item2':'value2a', 'item3':'value3a'},
          {'item1': 'value1b', 'item2':'value2b', 'item3':'value3b'},
      ];

    var content = '';
    $.each(object, function(key,value) { 
       content += '<li>'+ value.item1 + '</li>';    
    });
    $('.my-div').html(content);
});
```